# Synchronization of Iframes

Tags: asp.net, iframe

I have multiple iframes which are displaying same collection of data (help in asp.net Cache).

After the modifies the data on one of the frames, I would like all of the others to reflect the update without the need for explicit postback on each one of them.

So the question is: What is the easiest and most elegant way to keep iframes synchronized in this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'm yet to see an elegant iframe solution, but it's a pragmatic solutions to certain problems. Here's a few ideas:

- Post your changes to the top level frame and rebuild all the frames
- Use a custom javascript to update the necessary frames on changes
- Use a custom javascript to update the top level frame on changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have implemented you second suggestion. However, in the final solution I managed to avoid usage of iframes, which is in any case much better :)

Thanks....